# how to determine a fully rendered page within js?

Tags: javascript, dom, preventdefault

My mission is to load a script after the page is fully rendered, both css and js wise.

What I tried so far is:

- side loading with a page popstate counter,
- loading it via "defer" and "async" attribute,
- loading it via another script with "defer" attribute,
- via "onpageshow" event,
- via "DomContentLoaded-----" event,
- the "onload" event.

But all have the same result.

The part of this matter I don't understand is: the script that I try to load is of type "module" and it imports various functions from an already-loaded js file. That already-loaded js file prevents the default action on form elements to do a "submit" action.

But when I append the script I want to run after the page is fully rendered, it just reloads the entire page.

So why does the page reload if one the previous scripts already added a `preventDefault` on all forms for the submit action?

Any suggestions to prevent a page reload?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should try to add a minimal, reproducible example here as a snippet. Because all of the methods mentioned _should_ / _could_ work, and your page should _never_ just reload when loading a script unless the script does this. I don't think your issue will be found so much in when the script is loaded anymore, but on what the script is doing. But that's impossible to determine with the information given.

Comment: first i load my main script file, which exports and imports various functions from or to other js files. Other js files rely on functions and objects that are within that file. and the file i try to load is loaded via that main file.  the loaded file runs "some3=()=>{let a0=f.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ,._#]/g,'').substring(0,39);if(a0.length>=4){f.value=a0;h.click()}}" where "f" is the input element and "h" is the submit button. when both of the scripts are rendered it should work.

Comment: If you thought that clarified _anything_ you are sorely mistaken. I know how loading works, how modules work etc... I don't understand your problem really, and as far as I can ascertain, the problem won't really be related to loading but more to what your script actually does.  For brevity and clarification, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean it that way. The problem is the action that is the default for submit button. It should already be prevented, by the main script, which performs all form actions. So when i try to click that button via an another scripts the forms default action kicks in and reloads the entire page. I added a "g.form.onsubmit=(what)=>what.preventDefault();" in the secondary file, but this helps but is not quite what i'm looking for.

Comment: I'm such a "I"diot, i just forgot to call the already implemented submit function.

Comment: Haha, not an issue, glad you found it by yourself! Does confirm my suspiciokn that it has nothing to do with the loading part :) good luck going forward! Cheers